# Simplify SQL code

Tags: sql, sql-server

I made some individual queries which I wanted to combine in one table. Each query retrieves the date and value of F1, F2, F3 and the total.

I wanted to know if I could possibly make this query easier and especially how this can be achieved. So less code but achieve the same thing. Especially when I want to expand it to F20 later on.

The querys just add the data together each 15 mins.

```
2017-09-20 10:15    |49.0000|f1.1 
2017-09-20 10:15    |40.0000|f1.2 
2017-09-20 10:15    |11.0000|f1.3
2017-09-20 10:15    |0.0000|f1.4     
2017-09-20 10:15    |0.0000 |f1.5
2017-09-20 10:15    |0.0000 |f1.6
```

The query gives me the sum of date. 2017-09-20 10:15

If I try the conditional aggregation. It gives the sum of all deltavalues. But it should only sum the values with same date.

```
declare @days int
set @days = -165

SELECT a.Date, a.F1, b.F2, c.F3, d.Total
FROM
(SELECT rv.Date, sum(rv.value_num) as F1
FROM         dbo.Channels c INNER JOIN
                          (SELECT     rv.*, TRY_CONVERT(numeric(20, 4), rv.Value) AS value_num, (LEFT(TRY_CONVERT(datetime2(0), rv.Timestamp), 16)) AS Date
                            FROM          dbo.RecordedValues rv) rv ON c.SourceId = rv.SourceId AND c.Id = rv.ChannelId
WHERE   c.Tag LIKE N'%F1%'
AND Timestamp BETWEEN DATEADD(day,@days,GETDATE()) AND GETDATE()
GROUP BY  rv.Date
) as a,

(SELECT rv.Date, sum(rv.value_num) as F2
FROM         dbo.Channels c INNER JOIN
                          (SELECT     rv.*, TRY_CONVERT(numeric(20, 4), rv.Value) AS value_num, (LEFT(TRY_CONVERT(datetime2(0), rv.Timestamp), 16)) AS Date
                            FROM          dbo.RecordedValues rv) rv ON c.SourceId = rv.SourceId AND c.Id = rv.ChannelId
WHERE   c.Tag LIKE N'%F2%'
AND Timestamp BETWEEN DATEADD(day,@days,GETDATE()) AND GETDATE()
GROUP BY  rv.Date
) as b,

(  SELECT rv.Date, sum(rv.value_num) as F3
FROM         dbo.Channels c INNER JOIN
                          (SELECT     rv.*, TRY_CONVERT(numeric(20, 4), rv.Value) AS value_num, (LEFT(TRY_CONVERT(datetime2(0), rv.Timestamp), 16)) AS Date
                            FROM          dbo.RecordedValues rv) rv ON c.SourceId = rv.SourceId AND c.Id = rv.ChannelId
WHERE   c.Tag LIKE N'%F3%'
AND Timestamp BETWEEN DATEADD(day,@days,GETDATE()) AND GETDATE()
GROUP BY  rv.Date

) as c,

(SELECT rv.Date, sum(rv.value_num) as Total
FROM         dbo.Channels c INNER JOIN
                          (SELECT     rv.*, TRY_CONVERT(numeric(20, 4), rv.Value) AS value_num, (LEFT(TRY_CONVERT(datetime2(0), rv.Timestamp), 16)) AS Date
                            FROM          dbo.RecordedValues rv) rv ON c.SourceId = rv.SourceId AND c.Id = rv.ChannelId
WHERE   c.Tag LIKE N'%F%'
AND Timestamp BETWEEN DATEADD(day,@days,GETDATE()) AND GETDATE()
GROUP BY  rv.Date

) as d
where a.Date = b.Date
AND b.Date = c.Date
AND c.Date = d.Date
```

This how it currently gives my values:

```
RecDate             F1    |F2 |F3 |Total 
2017-09-20 10:15|   100   |200|100|400
2017-09-20 10:30|   150   |200|150|500
2017-09-20 10:45|   125   |200|100|425
2017-09-20 11:00|   110   |210|110|440
etc.
```

Comment: Even if you simplify the query, performance will be *bad*, because each clause like `LIKE '%F1%` will force a full table scan. What does `tag` contain?

Comment: It would be a big help if you could provide a sample of your original data, and what you are expecting your output to look like. Take a look at the [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for some tips on refining your question.

Comment: Why `(LEFT(TRY_CONVERT(datetime2(0), rv.Timestamp), 16)` ? You cast *something* to datetime2 then to a string, then you truncate it? Why? Did you want to cast something to a `date` perhaps? What is the type of `Timestamp` ?

Comment: @panagiotisKanovas timestamp is datetime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your current query, you are doing cross joining all the tables which is worst performance wise. Instead use `Case..When`, as It seems to be the perfect approach for your problem.

As I don't know the schema and the reason behind conversions of timestamp and date, all I can suggest is following query:

```
declare @days int
set @days = -165

SELECT rv.Date, 
 sum(case when c.Tag LIKE N'%F1%' then rv.value_num else 0 end) as F1,
 sum(case when c.Tag LIKE N'%F2%' then rv.value_num else 0 end) as F2,
 sum(case when c.Tag LIKE N'%F3%' then rv.value_num else 0 end) as F3,
 sum(case when c.Tag LIKE N'%F%' then rv.value_num  else 0 end) as total,
FROM dbo.Channels c 
INNER JOIN
        (SELECT rv.*, TRY_CONVERT(numeric(20, 4), rv.Value) AS value_num, 
(LEFT(TRY_CONVERT(datetime2(0), rv.Timestamp), 16)) AS Date
        FROM dbo.RecordedValues rv) rv 
ON c.SourceId = rv.SourceId AND c.Id = rv.ChannelId
WHERE  
rv.Timestamp BETWEEN DATEADD(day,@days,GETDATE()) AND GETDATE()
GROUP BY  rv.Date;
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: I tried it but it doesn't sum anymore. It doesn't give my the values like I put in my post now. I get every minute a zero and every 15 min a weird value. My original data gives only every 15 min a value.

Comment: can you create test data on sqlfiddle or rextester?

Comment: I added the else and end part of case. Try it now.

Comment: No problem. Please try the updated query. If it still don't work, then add your create and insert queries for both tables in your question.

Comment: I still doesn't work. But now I understand what it does wrong. Instead of adding the deltavalues of F1 and F2 up every 15 min. It's adding all the deltavalues up together and it updates that total value every 15 min. But I only need the amount on the exact 15 minutes. I will add my post to explain where this data comes from.

Comment: you commented on other answer that you forgot to mention something in your question. In order to solve your problem, please add the missing part in question.

Comment: I added it in my main post. Could you have a look at it. I hope you understand it. It looks like it's not grouping by date, which is weird.

Comment: Go to the following link and then tell me that is what you want or not? : http://rextester.com/ZTFE30917

Comment: Yes I went through the link! Thanks. That is what I wanted. I just made a mistake in copying the code

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional aggregation to simplify this code :

```
SELECT rv.date,
       SUM(CASE WHEN t.Tag LIKE N'%F1%' THEN rv.value_num ELSE 0 END) as f1,
       SUM(CASE WHEN t.Tag LIKE N'%F2%' THEN rv.value_num ELSE 0 END) as f2,
       SUM(CASE WHEN t.Tag LIKE N'%F3%' THEN rv.value_num ELSE 0 END) as f3,
       SUM(CASE WHEN t.Tag LIKE N'%F%' THEN rv.value_num ELSE 0 END) as total
FROM dbo.channels t
JOIN (SELECT  rv.*, TRY_CONVERT(numeric(20, 4), rv.Value) AS value_num, (LEFT(TRY_CONVERT(datetime2(0), rv.Timestamp), 16)) AS Date                     
      FROM  dbo.RecordedValues rv
      WHERE  rv.Timestamp BETWEEN DATEADD(day,@days,GETDATE()) AND GETDATE()) rv
 ON (c.SourceId = rv.SourceId AND c.Id = rv.ChannelId)
GROUP BY  rv.Date
```

That way you only scan the tables once.

Note that you should alias every column used -> `Timestamp` isn't aliased and I don't know from which table it comes.

Comment: It is from RecordedValues. So it should be like rv.Timestamp am I right?

Comment: Exactly @IonK. It's not wrong to not write it, but you should either use alias for all, or use alias for non. Be consistent :)

Comment: I tried it but it doesn't work. It now doesn't sum anymore per each timeframe.

Comment: I forgot to mention. Like %..% searches for a couple of tags which then sums them each 15 mins.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need conditional aggregation

```
SELECT rv.Date, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN c.Tag LIKE N'%F%' THEN rv.value_num END) as Total,
       SUM(CASE WHEN c.Tag LIKE N'%F1%' THEN rv.value_num END) as F1,
       SUM(CASE WHEN c.Tag LIKE N'%F2%' THEN rv.value_num END) as F2,
       SUM(CASE WHEN c.Tag LIKE N'%F3%' THEN rv.value_num END) as F3
FROM         dbo.Channels c 
INNER JOIN (
   SELECT rv.*, 
          TRY_CONVERT(numeric(20, 4), rv.Value) AS value_num, 
          LEFT(TRY_CONVERT(datetime2(0), rv.Timestamp), 16) AS Date
   FROM dbo.RecordedValues rv
  ) rv ON c.SourceId = rv.SourceId AND c.Id = rv.ChannelId
AND Timestamp BETWEEN DATEADD(day,@days,GETDATE()) AND GETDATE()
GROUP BY  rv.Date
```